# Proof of $2^n$ X $2^n $ can be covered in L shaped pieces chessboard without one square. How to prove with matrices?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have seen the solution to this puzzle. All the solutions that I came across are "word and picture" solutions and not proved in a way we usually prove induction. I am wondering, is there a way to prove this puzzle in a more universal way. My thought is that we could look at the chess board as a matrix of dimension $2^n$X $2^n$.

for n = 1 we could write:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 1  \\
   1 & 0   \\
   \end{bmatrix} or\begin{bmatrix} 
   0 & 1  \\
   1 & 1   \\
   \end{bmatrix}or \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0  \\
   1 & 1   \\
   \end{bmatrix}or \begin{bmatrix} 
   0 & 1  \\
   1 & 1  \\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
for $n \rightarrow n+1:$
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\ 
   1 & 1 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0  \\
   \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
   0 & 1 & 1   \\
   \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 0\\   
   1 & 1 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 0   \\
   \end{bmatrix} + ... =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots 1 & \vdots1  \\
1 & 1 & \cdots 1&  0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is construction of a proof based on idea with matrices possible ?

Comment: "...and not proved in a way we usually prove induction." No idea what this means.

Comment: A) The standard way of proving this is via induction. You could write that up using matrices, which seemed to be what you're doing in $n \rightarrow n+1$ B) In the last equation, the third matrix has 4 1's.

Comment: If you want to use matrices to draw the relevant pictures, that's fine. I just don't see the point, but the matrices were surely meant to be 4x4 rather than 4x3?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, they should be 4x4, anyway I thought it would be a different proof than pictures, looks like it isnt't.